# How to produce grouped column from many rows on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

If i could produce this result from many to many relationship from this kind of query:

```
SELECT x1.id AS id1, x3.id AS id3
 FROM humans x1
   LEFT JOIN memberships x2
     ON x1.id = x2.human_id
   LEFT JOIN groups x3
     ON x2.group_id = x3.id
 WHERE x1.id IN ( 1,2,3,4 )
 ORDER BY 1,2

id1 | id3 
----+----
1   | A
1   | B 
1   | C
2   | D
2   | E
3   | F
4   | (null)
5   | G
5   | Z
```

how to convert it into this kind of table?

```
id1 | id3s
----+--------
1   | A, B, C
2   | D, E
3   | F
4   | (null)
5   | G, Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string_agg` and a group by:

```
SELECT x1.id AS id1, string_agg(x3.id,',' order by x3.id asc) AS id3s
 FROM humans x1
   LEFT JOIN memberships x2
     ON x1.id = x2.human_id
   LEFT JOIN groups x3
     ON x2.group_id = x3.id
 WHERE x1.id IN ( 1,2,3,4 )
 GROUP BY x1.id
 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: just a minor addition - I'd add `order by` into string_agg to get consistent results - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f7451/7